# Front end collision has there been frame damage and identifying parts needed?

Tags: honda, part-identification, frame

I was in an accident and had front end damage. I'm trying to find the part name for the black plastic piece under the headlight? [image]

Also, I don't know if this piece that is bent is attached to the frame or not? Can it be straighten?

Thank you! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thge only way to identify if there has been frame damage is to measure the frame from its identifying points and check that it is still "square" about the centre line. So, just from a picture can't say if the frame is damaged...

This involves (at the most basic level) finding points on the shell or frame and dropping plumb lines down to the floor to mark out the relative positions, then measuring between the centreline and the points to work out what has moved. it also means checking the height of each point from the floor...

Body shops do this (at least good ones) so that they can "pull" the frame or chassis back into its correct position. I had a Volvo corrected at one body shop : Volvos are tough - they broke a chain...

Comment: Do you know the name of the black plastic part under the headlight (first image) I wanted to purchase this.

Comment: headlamp lower trim... go for the obvious - a parts guy will find it...